# TextMate's default CSS bundle throws an error when trying to use code complete

Tags: css, textmate, textmatebundles

I like code complete for CSS because sometimes I forget what values are available for a property. Unfortunately it seems that TextMate's default CSS bundle errors when trying to use it's implementation of Code Complete.

The error it generates is...

```
/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/codecompletion.rb:319:in     /bin/bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of filemap' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

from /tmp/temp_textmate.U2Q62Q:11

...any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've Google'd everywhere and can't find an actual solution!

M.

Comment: Does it matter for which property it’s trying to autocomplete the values, or does it happen for all of them?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! It happens for all properties

Answer (score 0):

Have you redownloaded the CSS bundle?
Did you try reinstalling Textmate (redownloading the .app and dragging it. It shouldn't remove your previous settings.)